# How to use EmojiOne with Ionic3 and Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, emojione

I just wanna use `EmojiOne` on an `Ionic3` app.

Here is the repository:
https://github.com/emojione/emojione

Here is the function I wanna use: `unicodeToImage`:

https://github.com/emojione/emojione/blob/master/lib/js/emojione.js#L316

But as you can see it is plain `Javascript`.

I don't wanna change anything inside the code on `node_modules` after I install it with: `npm install emojione` (as they recommend), because I want my app be ready for future updates.

Any idea on how I can import this library into my Ionic3 app?

Thanks!

Comment: node_modules is the right way, you need to update your project for future releases

Comment: yes, but how the `import` line looks like inside the `.ts` file? `import { ??? } from '???';`

Comment: https://github.com/emojione/emojione/blob/master/examples/JAVASCRIPT.md   this should give a basic example on how to use it after you put it in node modules

Comment: that indicates how to use it with `Javascript`, but I need to use it with `Typescript` (`.ts` file) using `import { ??? } from '???'`. The stack is: `Typescript -> Angular -> Ionic3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a javascript library in ts environment (when it is not ES6), you need to use type declaration file.

There seems to be one for emojione package in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/emojione).

Do:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/emojione
```

and in your ts file

```
import * as emojione from emojione;
```

You can find the declaration file in [definitelyTyped project](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/emojione)